# How to Get Netrw to exclude certain files?

Tags: netrw

I have vim save my undo history in files named something like `.filename.js.un~`, but I don't want this cluttering up my list of file in vim (in Netrw).

Is there a way to exclude all files with a certain file extension in Netrw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case,

```
let g:netrw_list_hide='.*\.un\~$'
```

will do the trick.  See

```
:help /~
```

for why the extra backslash preceding the tilde is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `g:netrw_list_hide`. e.g.

```
let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.swp$'
let g:netrw_hide = 1
```

For more information see `:h g:netrw_list_hide` and `:h netrw-edithide`

Comment: This looks good, but I can't seem to figure out a command that works for excluding the undo files. I tried `let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.un~$'` and it doesn't work.